# Replicate BTOA Javascript Function in SAS Data Step

Tags: javascript, sas, base64

When I encrypt the string `g.b@yahoo.it` in Javascript using the BTOA function I get the result `Zy5iQHlhaG9vLml0`.

This function converts the string to the base64 representation of the string.  When I try and do the equivalent in SAS I get a different value:

```
proc fcmp outlib=common.funcs.funcs; 
  function b64(string $) $; 
  length digest $32767; 
  digest=strip(put(string,$base64x32767.)); 
  return(digest); 
  endsub; 
quit; 

data email; 
  input email $12.; 
  datalines; 
g.b@yahoo.it 
run; 

data X; 
  set email; 
  e1 = "<" || trim(email) || ">"; 
  pw_e = b64(e1); 
  put _all_;
run;
```

Gives me:

```
email=g.b@yahoo.it e1=<g.b@yahoo.it> pw_e=PGcuYkB5YWhvby5pdD4= _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
```

Based on the documentation for each, they are using the same alphabet:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003161924.htm

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp

I want to replicate the same function in SAS Data Step to obtain the same result.  Is there a way to do this in SAS?

Comment: What have you tried? Base64 encoding in SAS is demonstrated at https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/base64-encoding/td-p/15264

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to replicate this step: 

function encode (email) {
var e1 = "<"+email+">"
var crip = btoa(e1)
}

In SAS the data step is:

proc fcmp outlib=work.func.cipher;
function b64(string $) $;
length digest $32767;
digest=strip(put(string,$base64x32767.));
return(digest);
endsub;
quit;

data email;
input email $12.;
datalines;
g.b@yahoo.it
run;

data X;
set email;
e1 = "<" || trim(email) || ">";
pw_e = b64(e1);
run;

But i don't have the same result.
I think the problem is to use always the length 32767 and not the length of each emails.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow -- Edit your question and move the code you put in the comment into the question as 'more information'; and if you figure it out on your own you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

They are doing the same thing.  You are modifying the string that you are passing to the base64 encoding function in SAS which is why you are getting a different result.  The string you are using in SAS is `<g.b@yahoo.it>` (you added the `<` and `>` characters around it.

If you run that same string of `<g.b@yahoo.it>` through btoa() you get the same result of `PGcuYkB5YWhvby5pdD4=`